# Difference in meaning between "nun ja" and "na ja"

Tags: meaning

> I wasn't sure if I'd made the right choice. **Nun ja**, damit ist es nun vorbei. Das zählt.

On the surface, both "nun ja" and "na ja" appear to translate into "well" in English, but I assume they are not exactly interchangeable. How do these two differ in usage?

> {compared to}: I wasn't sure if I'd made the right choice. **Na ja**, damit ist es nun vorbei. Das zählt.

Answer (score 6):

The two choices are only separated by the tiniest nuance to me (German is my first language). "Nun ja" expresses more frustration, "Na ja" more dismissal and less caring.

Comment: Hi. The "nun" in "nun ja" has nothing to do with the "jetzt" meaning, correct?

Comment: @Alone-zee: I have no notion of such a connotation in this case.

Comment: It is an idiom. You cannot get its meaning by adding up the meanings of its separate elements. So, no, the *nun* does not carry its primary meaning as if in isolated use.

Comment: Nun, selbst alleinstehend hat es niemals die Bedeutung von "jetzt", weil "nun" in diesem Kontext ein Partikel ist und nicht ein Adverb. Man muss hier zwischen zwei ganz unterschiedlichen Wörtern unterscheiden, wenngleich es scheinbar dasselbe Wort ist.

Comment: I would also say that "nun ja" tends a bit more towards resignation/acceptance of facts than "na ja" does.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely correct, at least in my mind and from conversational/informal experience. Nun ja (resignation). Na ja (self-evidentiary).

Comment: "Absolutely correct" seems to be an answer or comment to another answer, not to the question. If you lack reputation to comment on answers, you have to collect that reputation. This is what we all had to went through. If your comment isn't worth collecting the reputation first, well …